# How do I set a default user for blog posts in Django?

Tags: django, model, migration

My Blog model has a User field like following:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Blog:
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blog', default=User('monty'))
```

This works as in I can see 'monty' set as a default user in the admin interface when I create a blog post. However, when I make migrations, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <User: >
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

I also tried this:

```
default=User.objects.filter(username='monty'))
```

and that returns a slightly different error when I make migrations:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <User: monty>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

Does anyone know how to get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a callable that determines the `User` object, so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def get_monty():
    if get_monty.user:
        return user
    user, __ = get_user_model().get_or_create(username='monty')
    get_monty.user = user
    return user
    
get_monty.user = None

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='blog',
        default=get_monty
    )
```

That being said, I think it makes no sense to specify a default here. Your views can determine the logged in user and set that as the author. By using a default you likely will eventually end up with some `Post`s for which the view did not implement the logic, and are thus all assigned to `monty`, it
thus will silence an error that probably should not be silenced.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).